# Ruby-newbie routing error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing my first routing rule in rails and I am getting some errors.

```
No route matches "/index.html"
```

In my routes.rb file I do have this:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home#index"
```

and further below it I have this:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

and also I have been getting errors about not having the controller set up.  But I was going through this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and there were no explicit steps to set them up.

Is my mapping incorrect?  How can I fix this? :)
Thanks!

Also, here is a url where you can see the fuller error :)
http://128.28.204.195:3000/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  ... other routes ...

  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

You don't need get "home#index". 
After you can use root_path() or root_url() helpers for link to your home page.